# Method to modify bounding box co-ordinates

Tags: python, image-processing

I have 8 points for every image in my dataset, (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4).

My objective is to train Retina net, but the repository requires that the format be like

`path/to/image.jpg,x1,y1,x2,y2,class_name`

they only demand 4 points, something like this `/data/imgs/img_001.jpg,837,346,981,456,cow`

My 8 points for one image look like this - `[[220, 129], [1028,113], [1098,684], [206,706]`

Is there any way i could convert my 8 points to 4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like your input region is not a rectangle, but Retina expects one. Find `minx, miny` and `maxx, maxy` and use those values. (Just a guess - I don't know what Retina is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the four pairs are just four x,y points in the image that should be in the bounding box,

```
>>> vals = [[220, 129], [1028,113], [1098,684], [206,706]]
>>> bbox = [min([x[0] for x in vals]), min([x[1] for x in vals]),
...         max([x[0] for x in vals]), max([x[1] for x in vals])]
>>> print(bbox)
[206, 113, 1098, 706]
>>> imgpath = 'path/to/image.jpg'
>>> print('{},{},{}'.format(imgpath, ','.join(map(str, bbox)), 'clsname'))
path/to/image.jpg,206,113,1098,706,clsname
```

Comment: Hi Adam ,Thanks for the quick response, Let me try this out, in the mean time......